# How to print of value of i in one line by for loop

Tags: python-3.x

I write this code:

```
for i in range(0,7):
     print(i)
```

so simply the output will be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

But i want to print like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

how can I print this output like that.??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Comment: `print(i, end=' ') `

Comment: got it....!! and its done...thank you so much @Idos,@Rakesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following in Python3. If you want more information check out the documentation on the print function [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print). And you can read about the unpacking operator [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

```
print(*list(range(0, 7)), sep = " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

1) make a string first, then print it

```
" ".join([str(i) for i in range(0, 7)])
```

2) [Duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/493399/3776268) How to print with out a new line

You should Google these things first...